# About 2D-array pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Here defined an array:

```
int a[2][5]={{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10}};
```

and what does the statement mean?:

```
int *p = (int*)(&a+1);
```

Why the output of `*p` is 6 ?

```
printf("%d",*p);//6
```

Especially, please explain what `(int*)` and `&a+1` mean.

Comment: Time to take many hours to read a good *C programming* book. We don't have time to teach you *C*.

Comment: Please consider Google as your source of information.

Comment: If you expect `6` if `int *p = (int *)(&a[0]+1);`

Answer (score 2):

First a note, `int a[2][5] = {1,2,3,4,5};` is not a totally valid array definition.

`gcc` issues thoses warnings:

> test.c:10:3: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
>
> test.c:10:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘a[0]’) [-Wmissing-braces]

Your array is `2`x`5`, which means it should have 10 elements: `int a[2][5]={{1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9,10}};` is a more correct definition.

Now, to the question: `int *p = (int*)(&a+1);`. This declares a pointer to `int` nammed p. `(int *)` is a cast. So you're basically casting `(&a + 1)` to a `(int *)`.

However, note that `(&a + 1)` *is not the same thing* as `a[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Define your array like this:

```
int a[2][5]={{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10}};
```

Then use your array:

```
int * p = (int*)(&a[0][0]+1);
```

or

```
int * p = (int*)(a+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`&a` evaluates to the address of the array `a`. 
Adding 1 to the address of the array will add 1 times the size of what the array contains.  In this case, the array `a` contains arrays of 5 `int`, so the expression evaluates to the address of an int 5 `int` away from the address of the array, or the address of the `int` `6`.